# Decomposition of the Photon Propagator into $K$ and $G$ propagators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, research-level, infrared-radiation

I am reading a paper by B. Sahoo and A. Sen, called "Classical and Quantum Results on Logarithmic Terms in the Soft Theorem in Four Dimensions". To determine the logarithmically divergent behavior of the subleading soft factors in loop diagrams (complex scalar QED), in Section 5, they employ the use of a photon propagator in the Feynman gauge, that is decomposed as follows
$$-i\frac{\eta^{\mu\nu}}{l^2-i\epsilon}=-i\frac{1}{l^2-i\epsilon}
\Big\{
K^{\mu\nu}_{(ab)}+G^{\mu\nu}_{(ab)}
\Big\}.$$
I believe that this decomposition was inspired in a paper I found in the references of that paper, written by Yennie and Grammer, and called
"Improved Treatment for the Infrared-Divergence Problem in QED" (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.8.4332).

Then, one can think of as the Feynman diagrams containing one additional virtual photon as sums of two diagrams, one containing a $K^{\mu\nu}_{(ab)}$ factor in its amplitude and one containing a $G^{\mu\nu}_{(ab)}$ factor. This is equivalent to saying that there exist two kinds of photons: one (called the $K-$ photon) associated to the $K^{\mu\nu}_{(ab)}$ contribution and one (called the $G-$photon) associated to the $G^{\mu\nu}_{(ab)}$ contribution to the amplitude. The formula for $K^{\mu\nu}_{(ab)}$ is chosen to be
$$K^{\mu\nu}_{(ab)}=l^{\mu}l^{\nu}
\frac{(2p_a\cdot l-l)\cdot(2p_b\cdot l+l)}{(2p_a\cdot l-l^2+i\epsilon)(2p_b\cdot l+l^2-i\epsilon)}$$
and $G^{\mu\nu}_{(ab)}=\eta^{\mu\nu}-K^{\mu\nu}_{(ab)}$. The labels $a$ and $b$ are labels indicating matter particles and all the momenta are thought to be incoming (hence the "+" sign accompanying particles of type $b$). The questions I have are the following

1. First of all, I would like to ensure that the two components of the photon propagator are not related to photon directions in any way (this might be a bit silly). I am expressing this question because I have seen other decompositions of the photon propagator to transverse and longitudinal components, such as $-i\frac{\eta^{\mu\nu}}{l^2-i\epsilon}=
   -i\frac{1}{l^2-i\epsilon}(\eta^{\mu\nu}-\frac{l^{\mu}l^{\nu}}{l^2})-
   i\frac{1}{l^2-i\epsilon}\frac{l^{\mu}l^{\nu}}{l^2}$, where the first part is transverse and the second part is longitudinal.
2. The authors in "Classical and Quantum Results on Logarithmic Terms in the Soft Theorem in Four Dimensions" refer to the $K-$ photon as the photon that causes infrared divergences in loop integrals. This is something I am fairly okay with, as I can construct a simple Feynman diagram containing one loop and verify that the contribution from the $K$ propagator is of the form
   $$\int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{l^2-i\epsilon}
   \frac{(2p_a\cdot l-l)\cdot(2p_b\cdot l+l)}{(2p_a\cdot l-l^2+i\epsilon)(2p_b\cdot l+l^2-i\epsilon)}$$
   (up to some sign errors) that diverge logarithmically in the soft/infrared limit (see Weinberg's "Infrared Photons and Gravitons"). The remaining $G-$ photon graphs are said to yield IR finite amplitudes (if additional radiation is added to the diagrams, otherwise they vanish). Is there a quick way to see this? I would think constructing a simple loop $G-$ photon diagram again with one additional external (soft) photon and see that the integrand goes like $k\times l^{-4}\sim l^{-3}$ (not sure about the last step-approximation), but what about the cases in which the additional external photon is not soft? Will the amplitude be IR finite in that case as well?
3. When the authors perform the $K-$ photon loop integrals, they approximate the region of integration for the virtual $K-$ photon energy to be much greater than the energy of the soft external photons $k^0$(hence this would be the lower boundary in the integral) and much less than the typical energies of the matter particles (hence some cutoff is probalby the upper boundary of the integral). Why are we allowed to perform the integration discarding the energies below the soft energy $k^0$? Has somehow the integral of the $K-$ photons taken care of that region of integration? What of the remaining integration regions (above the remaining particle energies)?

Any help will be appreciated!